# Solution verification on Rudin RCA Chapter 1, Problem 12

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

**Problem** Suppose $f \in L^1 (\mu)$. Prove that to each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $\displaystyle \int_E |f| d\mu < \epsilon$ whenever $\mu (E) < \delta$.

**Solution** Let $$\chi _ n(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & (x \in [n, n + 1) ) \\ 0 & (\text{otherwise})\end{cases}.$$
$\chi_n$ is obviously measurable, and so is the function $\chi_n \circ |f|$.

Since $\displaystyle \int_X |f| d\mu < \infty$, the set $E = \{x \in X : f(x) = \infty \}$ has zero measure.

From the fact above, we can tell that
$$\displaystyle c = \int_X |f| d\mu = \int_{X - E} |f| d\mu = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} a_i < \infty,$$
where $a_i = \int_{X - E} \chi_i \circ |f|$.

There exists a number $n$ such that $\displaystyle \sum_{i = n}^{\infty} a_i < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. It is trivial that $\mu \left( |f|^{-1}([n, \infty)) \right)$ is finite, because otherwise the integral would diverge. Let the previous value be $\delta_1$. Also let $\delta_2 = \displaystyle \frac{\epsilon}{2n}$.

Let $\delta = \min(\delta_1, \delta_2)$ and $Y$ is any set which satisfies $\mu(Y) < \delta$. Because $X - E = |f|^{-1} ([n, \infty)) \cup |f|^{-1} ([0, n))$ and two set is disjoint, the following inequality holds.

$$\begin{align}
 \int_Y |f| d\mu =&& \int_{Y \cap |f|^{-1} ([n, \infty))} |f| d\mu +&& \int_{Y \cap |f|^{-1} ([0, n))} |f| d\mu +&& \int_{Y \cap E} |f| d\mu \\
  <&& \frac{\epsilon}{2} +&& n \cdot \mu \left( Y \cap |f|^{-1} ([0, n)) \right) +&& 0 \\
<&&\epsilon&& 
\end{align}
$$
So it is proven that $\displaystyle \int_{Y} |f| d\mu < \epsilon$ when $\mu(Y) < \delta$.

---

How does it look? Does it contain any critical errors?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I edited my question so it is stated more clearly.

Comment: Looks alright now.